# C++ Windows DLL using try-catch block internally fails

Tags: c++, windows, exception, dll, try-catch

I am trying to create a Windows DLL using gcc version 4.7.2, however I'm facing problems when I use Exceptions internally. In the DLL code I am throwing an exception found in `test()` method which is caught in the same method. Below is the code found in main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "dllexport.h"

using namespace std;

ADDAPI int test()
{
    try
    {
        throw 2;
    }catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Link to correct DllMain if C++ is used
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD  reason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

and the relevant header found in dllexport.h

```
#ifndef DLLEXPORT_H
#define DLLEXPORT_H

/* Define calling convention in one place, for convenience. */
#define ADDCALL __stdcall

/* Usually format is ADDAPI int ADDCALL Add(int a, int b)...
   but moving ADDCALL near ADDAPI works in gcc */

/* You should define BUILDING_DLL *only* when building the DLL. */
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
  #define ADDAPI __declspec(dllexport) ADDCALL
#else
  #define ADDAPI __declspec(dllimport) ADDCALL
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    ADDAPI int test();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* DLLEXPORT_H */
```

This compiles fine, however when I try to call the test method from a process which links to it, the following error is returned:

***This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.***

I compile the dll using the following:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -O3 -DBUILDING_DLL
g++ -o mydll.dll main.o -shared -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Additionally, I compile the client application using `-lmydll`. I understand that it is risky to throw exceptions from DLLs and catching them in a process, however I am not doing so, as exceptions will all be handled internally in the DLL.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Removing static linking of libstdc++ to the DLL solves the issue. However, it would be ideal if the DLL resolved all the dependencies internally, in order for it to be self-contained. What can I do to attain the above?

Comment: Does it say "Caught"?

Comment: That's a message that's produced by the Microsoft CRT.  Mixing different CRT versions in one program very rarely comes to a good end.

Comment: @doctorlove No, it crashes the process instantly.
Hans, However, both the DLL and the program using it have been compiled with the same compiler.. Should this still be the case?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ Using mingw. But no, try removing the try/catch to confirm that has anything to do with the crash.

Comment: Removing the try/catch works.

Moreover, I compiled the dll this time without statically including libstdc++ and it worked! Why does this work? Also, it would be ideal for me if I could include libstdc++ statically.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and it appears that I had to compile the client application also with below line

```
-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

in order that it works.